Oracle update between dates
So I'm trying to update a table based off if a date is between a range of two dates, but rather than updating the field if the date falls outside the two ranges, its updating regardless
update tablex
set field = 1 
where tableid = 1
and to_date('10/14/2024', 'mm/dd/yyyy') not between trunc(sysdate) and trunc(sysdate - 15);

Shouldn't this skip updating the field as the 10/14/24 date is between sysdate and sysdate-15 (9/30/2024)?

Try between trunc(sysdate-15) and trunc(sysdate) The lower value must be the first one.

nothing in your date predicate refers to the table ... you are comparing a literal with two functions (sysdate), so if it's true (after fixing your swapped order for between), it's true for 100% of your rows. It's meaningless to do this. If you want to update 100% of the table, it'd be easier just to leave out the predicate entirely. I suspect, however, what you meant to do is to refer to a date column in your table. If instead you really do intend to update 0% or 100% based on a condition outside your table, use PL/SQL IF THEN logic to do that, not SQL predicates.

It appears that your "to_date('10/14/2024', 'mm/dd/yyyy')" is not in the correct format.
If the column that contains date is already in a date format, you'll want to do this:
-- Replace your_date_column with the correct column name --
update tablex
set field = 1 
where tableid = 1
and (your_date_column not between trunc(sysdate - 15) and trunc(sysdate));

If the column that contains date is NOT in a date format, you'll want to do this:
-- Replace your_date_column with the correct column name --
update tablex
set field = 1 
where tableid = 1
and (to_date(your_date_column, 'MM/DD/YYYY') not between trunc(sysdate - 15) and trunc(sysdate));


this works, also credit to @WernfriedDomscheit for suggesting the same. didnt know the lower value should have come first

Does Oracle support BETWEEN SYMMETRIC, where it doesn't matter if the lower value comes first or last?

@jarlh - no, it doesn't. (Also, for OP's reference, the bit about lower value having to come first is in there too: "If expr3 < expr2, then the interval is empty.")
